Handling columns data when 100% missing but need to retrieve those values
I have almost 20 features. among them some are categorical and some are numerical. I already convert those categorical features into binary encoding. The problem is that among 20 features, two feature values (entire column) are 100% missing. later we realize that we need those features. How can we retrieve those values?

I don’t understand. Are you saying that previously there was no missing data, or that between two particular columns/features,  at least one instance is missing ? Either way, how did the missingness occur ?

When you say 100% missing, you mean that there is NaN everywhere in the column or that the colum is not in the dataframe anymore? Are these 2 features numerical or caregorical? did you transform these features?
